# Using Entity Framework for relating 3 entitites where 1 of them can only be related to either one of remaining two

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Suppose I have two entities, `bungalows` and `apartments`. Both of them have varying fields and cannot be interchanged however both these entities have multiple tenants. Each tenant can only be part of either one bungalow or one apartment. How do I achieve this using Entity Framework?

I was thinking of creating 2 more entities `bungalowTenants` and `apartmentTenants` and using these to map. Each `bungalowTenant` would have one instance of a `bungalow` and a `tenant` and similarly for `apartmentTenant`.

Bungalows would have a collection of bungalowTenants and apartment of apartmentTenants.

```
public class Bungalow
{        
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int HouseNumber { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public ICollection<BungalowTenants> Tenants { get; set; }
}

public class Apartment
{        
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ApartmentNumber{ get; set; }
        public string Wing{ get; set; }
        public string Building{ get; set; }
        public ICollection<ApartmentTenants> Tenants { get; set; }
}

public class Tenant
{        
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
}

public class ApartmentTenants
{        
        public int ApartmentId { get; set; }
        public Apartment Apartment{ get; set; }
        public int TenantId{ get; set; }
        public Tenant Tenant{ get; set; }
}

public class BungalowTenants
{        
        public int BungalowId{ get; set; }
        public Bungalow Bungalow{ get; set; }
        public int TenantId{ get; set; }
        public Tenant Tenant{ get; set; }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that it does not restrict in any way the same tenant to be a part of both, a bungalow and an apartment. I am unable to figure out how to do that using Entity Framework. I'd appreciate any help on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Not every business rule can be or needs to be translated to database constraints or model constraints.

And if you *would* enforce this, through model rules or programmed rules:

**What if** the tenants decide to *move* from a bungalow to an apartment? They will most probably want to start renting the new home days or even weeks before the cancellation date of the old one - or do you expect them to vacate the old home before midnight and enter the new home after midnight, with all their belongings packed in boxes on the pavement for a certain period? That does not seem very realistic.

Comment: Hi, that was just an example. What I need that for is actually too specific hence I used an analogy.

Comment: By application logic I can ensure that no repetitions happen, but I wanted to check if that can be done at database level. Also I kind of found a solution using pure SQL but couldn't translate it into entity framework.